# How to validate variable is actually a joi schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm trying to create a reusable function which you can pass in a joi schema and run validation against `req.body`. I want to validate my variable `schema` to ensure that it's a valid joi schema.

Is there a way to do this?

```
function validatePayload(schema) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    const valid = joi.validate(req.body, schema)
    if (valid.error) {
      return handleErr(res, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, valid.error.details[0].message)
    }

    return next()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that Joi internally validates a schema by checking if Joi constructor is found in the schema prototype chain, therefore, you probably can use the same validation:

```js
const mySchema = Joi.object().keys({
  username: Joi.string(),
  password: Joi.string()
});

const isValidSchema = mySchema instanceof Joi.constructor;

console.log(isValidSchema);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/joi-browser@13.4.0/dist/joi-browser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any object will result to true `{} instanceof Joi.constructor`

Answer (score 5):

There is now a dedicated method to check if supplied object is a schema

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')

const schema = Joi.any();
Joi.isSchema(schema); // true

const notSchema = {}
Joi.isSchema(notSchema); // false
```

https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#isschemaschema-options